# Scroll div before body

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have scrollable div. I want scroll the box on scrolldown or keydown but I have to click on the div to make it possible. Because when I try scroll it after page load then scrolled is the body.

What should I make to first scroll the div and after that body?

Comment: Start by posting the code you're already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the focus on the div.

With jQuery something like `$("#myDiv").focus();`.